# Using SSH and Paramiko in Python to connect to a remote server fails

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have recently downloaded and installed SSH from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.14 for my Python 2.7 64-bit

Then I tried to connect to a server which is a virtual machine on the network. I have full authorization to get access to it. My code is:

```
import ssh
import paramiko


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect('10.92.15.12', username = "testUser", password = "testPwd")
```

However, I've got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\testProj\testRemoteExecution.py", line 56, in <module>
    ssh.connect('10.92.15.12', username = "testUser", password = "testPwd")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 283, in connect
    sock.connect((hostname, port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

So did I make any mistake here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a SSH server running at 10.92.15.12? Can you connect to it using a regular SSH client, from the same machine as you are running your python script from?

Comment: @gurka Hi, sorry I have to ask a baby question as this is the first time i use ssh :(    What is a SSH server?

Comment: As an aside, notice that your code doesn't actually use the ssh module. `ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()` overrides it. That's probably good because the ssh module has been deprecated (it has been merged into paramiko) and you should use paramiko instead.

Comment: @ChangeMyName If you want to connect to your virtual machine via SSH you must have a SSH server running on the virtual machine. You should probably go ahead and read about SSH, to get a basic understanding of how it works, before trying to write a SSH client in Python.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell